# How to access a static property from another .ts file in a external module

Tags: typescript

Any ideas how I can access this static property in a external module? The class Game in game.ts contains the actual static property but Game is not accessable to the module GameObjects

```
///<reference path="game.ts" />

    export module GameObjects {



    export class Player implements GameObject {

        color: string = Game.staticProperty;
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are exporting classes from modules in this style, you'll need to import like this:

*game.ts*

```
export class Game {
    public static staticProperty = "Test";
}
```

*player.ts*

```
import game = module("game");

export class Player {
    public example = game.Game.staticProperty;
}
```

This will also generate the `require` statement to load the module for you.

Comment: ah I see I must export the class game then!