# Accessing a static member of a exported class within a module

Tags: typescript

I have some Typescript code:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
        static MyStaticMember : string;
    }
}
```

and I want to access it from a separately compiled file. I've tried:

```
MyModule.MyClass.MyStaticMember
```

but that gives an error:

```
error TS2094: The property MyClass does not exist on the value of type 'type MyModule'
```

How can I access this member variable?

Comment: Can you show how you are compiling your files?

Comment: Which module system is used?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in this file or the other one, you have a top-level `import` or `export`. This turns your file into an external module, which means that separate declarations `MyModule` create *new* modules instead of merging together.

See also

- [How do I use namespaces with TypeScript external modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules)
- [How to access a static property from another .ts file in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218797/how-to-access-a-static-property-from-another-ts-file-in-a-external-module?rq=1)